# Why System.IO.File doesn't work with uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have web page where user can upload excel files. Server side looks very simple

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadReport(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        file.SaveAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUploadPath"] +  Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx");
```

This works fine for me and uploaded file can be opened correctly. But then i changed my server code to this.

```
 string fileContent = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUploadPath"] +  Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx", fileContent);
```

File is also created and saved now but for some reason when i try to open it by Excel it is said that file is corrupted 
[image]

So, WHY modified code doesn't work and how to get file content correctly(I need to path it to another library) ?

Comment: why are you appending text to an excel file? It should always been File.SaveAs() if you want to save a file. If you want to read you cant read through stream reader perhps

Comment: why are you opening it as string? it's a binary file, use File.AppendAllBytes

Comment: `File.AppendAllText` takes two arguments, not one, as in your code.

Comment: @Alex. Sorry, i missed it when copy-paste. Corrected now

Comment: @Nissim But System.IO.File doesn't contain method AppendAllBytes

Comment: You should read it (download it) as a byte array and then use File.WriteAllBytes to save it.

Comment: @Polyfun. Thanks. Your suggestion works. If i convert file into byte[] and then use File.WriteAllBytes everything works as expected. With File.WriteAllText or File.AppendAllText i had described issue ...

Comment: @Polyfun But why WriteAllText doesn't work ? i don't understand at the moment

Comment: Because Excel files are not text files, but binary files (ZIP files internally), if you write them as text you corrupt them.